# KTor Gson DataConversion with interface

Tags: java, kotlin, gson, ktor

I am trying to register the `PubicKey` interface for data conversion in KTor so I can easily receive a public key like this:

```
data class StoreRequest(
    val publicKey: PublicKey
)
...
val publicKey: PublicKey = call.receive<StoreRequest>().publicKey
```

To achieve this I used this page: https://ktor.io/servers/features/data-conversion.html
I registered this data converter:

```
convert<PublicKey> {
    decode { values, _ ->
        // When I add a breakpoint here it won't be reached.
        values.singleOrNull()?.let { key ->
            val encryptedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key.split(" ")[1])
            val inputStream = DataInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedKey))

            val format = String(ByteArray(inputStream.readInt()).also(inputStream::readFully))

            if (format != "ssh-rsa") throw RuntimeException("Unsupported format")

            val publicExponent = ByteArray(inputStream.readInt()).also(inputStream::readFully)
            val modulus = ByteArray(inputStream.readInt()).also(inputStream::readFully)

            val spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(BigInteger(modulus), BigInteger(publicExponent))
            val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

            keyFactory.generatePublic(spec)
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason Gson is complaining because I'm using an interface:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.security.PublicKey. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem`
```

So I'm guessing that I need to create an `InstanceCreator` for an initial value.
This is the initial `PublicKey` class I created:

```
class PkTest : PublicKey {
    override fun getAlgorithm(): String = ""
    override fun getEncoded(): ByteArray = ByteArray(0)
    override fun getFormat(): String = ""
}
...
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    gson {
        setPrettyPrinting()
        registerTypeAdapter(PublicKey::class.java, InstanceCreator<PublicKey> { PkTest() // This is called when I add a breakpoint })
    }
}
```

But this also doesn't work! This is the exception I am getting:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 16 path $.publicKey
```

For some reason it's expecting the provided key to be a JSON object while I'm providing this:

```
{
    "publicKey": "ssh-rsa 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 dynmem@memmen.frl"
}
```

How can I 'trick' GSON in accepting a string for `PublicKey`? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

I think GSON wants to serialize a JSON object to a `PublicKey`. But I want it to accept a `String`. I think this should be possible because classes like `UUID` and `Date` work just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! Instead of using an `InstanceCreator` I used a `JsonDeserializer`:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    gson {
        setPrettyPrinting()
        registerTypeAdapter(PublicKey::class.java, JsonDeserializer<PublicKey> { json, _, _ ->
            // TODO some type checking.
            val key = json.asString
            val encryptedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key.split(" ")[1])
            val inputStream = DataInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedKey))

            val format = String(ByteArray(inputStream.readInt()).also(inputStream::readFully))

            if (format != "ssh-rsa") throw RuntimeException("Unsupported format")

            val publicExponent = ByteArray(inputStream.readInt()).also(inputStream::readFully)
            val modulus = ByteArray(inputStream.readInt()).also(inputStream::readFully)

            val spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(BigInteger(modulus), BigInteger(publicExponent))
            val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

            keyFactory.generatePublic(spec)
        })
    }
}
```

This part can fully be removed:

```
convert<PublicKey> {
    decode { values, _ ->
        ...
    }
}
```